# View inside Scrollview not show

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a component like this:

```
  <ScrollView style={{ width: '100%',backgroundColor:'#000' }}>
    <View style={{width:'100%', height: '100%', flex:1,backgroundColor:'#fff' }}>


    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

but above code, just shows a black screen, I have expected to show a white screen!
where is my wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you need to do is add a contentContainerStyle to your ScrollView:

```
contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
```

Plus you don't really need width: 100% and height: 100% rules, flex: 1 should be enough if you don't have any other elements on the same level.

So my proposed solution is:

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:'#000' }} contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <Text>Yo man</Text>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```